# How to fetch maven plugin from Github packages?

Tags: java, maven, github, github-actions, github-package-registry

I have deployed a java package to Github packages successfully, I tried to consume it **successfully** as a dependency:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

but I can't resolve(fetch) it as a maven plugin like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </plugin>
...
```

I am getting this error:

```
Plugin com.example:demo:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved:
Could not find artifact com.example:demo:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

also the `.m2/settings.xlm` is ready and works fine as I tested it by fetching the package as a dependency not plugin, and it contains:

```
<server>
      <id>github</id>
      <username>USER</username>
      <password>PERSONAL_TOKEN_SCOPE_REPO_W_R_PACKAGES</password>
</server>
<profile>
      <id>github</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>github</id>
          <name>GitHub OWNER Apache Maven Packages</name>
          <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/OWNER/REPO-NAME</url>
          <releases>
              <enabled>true</enabled>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
</profile>
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>github</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

Any Idea? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eureka! For fetching a plugin we should use `<pluginRepositories>` instead of `<repositories>` which is used for fetching dependencies.

> **Remember**: pluginRepositories contains the information needed for establishing  connections with remote repository.

My setup was right, I just needed to add this section inside `<profile>`:

```yaml
<pluginRepositories>
     <pluginRepository>
          <id>github</id>
          <name>GitHub OWNER Apache Maven Packages</name>
          <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/OWNER/REPO-NAME</url>

          <!-- next elements are up to you -->
          <releases>
              <enabled>true</enabled>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </snapshots>
     </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

See a sample `~/.m2/settings.xml` [here](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-settings/settings.html)

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to configure it the right way.

You can see a sample project with the working GitHub Actions CI and the GitHub Package Registry [here](https://github.com/TobseF/HelloMaven):

To see how the dependency can be included check the:
 [GitHub-plugin-registry-example Template](https://github.com/TobseF/github-plugin-registry-example)

The trick was to add an authentification to the GitHub API in the global maven `settings.xml`.

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>github</id>
        <username>YOUR_USERNAME</username>
        <password>YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

Replace the `YOUR_USERNAME` with your GitHub login name.
Replace the `YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN` with a generated GitHub personal access token:
*GitHub > Settings > Developer Settings > Personal access tokens > Generate new token:*
The token needs at least the read:packages scope. Otherwise you will get a Not authorized exception.

It wasn't clear that this auth is also needed to read a package. Especially because the jar is available without any login on the package page: https://github.com/TobseF/HelloMaven/packages

So it's a little bit nasty because we have to add the github... and hope others will also provide the the repository with the github id. Otherwise we have to add a server config for every github dependency.

Keep in mind that every GitHub repo is its own maven repo. So there is no global registry like the maven central. Every dependency has to provide its own repository link declaration.

But in combination with the GitHub Actions CI, it's a very nice alternative without any third party plugins.

Comment: Thanks @boetis . I noticed that you meant "dependency" not "Plugin" as I successfully able to fetch dependency but I can't fetch the package as a plugin. Did I understand u right?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I made a mistake. If my answer helped you, please checkmark it and upvote so it can help the community.

Comment: unfortunately ur answer is perfect for fetching a dependency, but not plugin which I need. and my issue is not authentication issue, as I said I tested my <server> tag by fetching dependency from the same repo and it was successful, and user as owner and password as token with scopes repo + package(w/r).

Comment: hi again, and thanks a lot for helping. I posted my solution down, maybe you would like to check it. have a nice day.